# Recursively copy /dev/null to file pattern

Tags: linux, command-line, zfs

I am using a ZFS system that has reached its disk quota.  As a result, the `rm` command no longer is available to me.  However, I am able to copy `/dev/null` to particular files to effectively remove them.

The issue is that the directory I am trying to clear out is roughly 40GB in size, and each file that has any girth is buried within 3 levels.

Is there a command line way to easily search and replace those files with `/dev/null`?  I could do it pretty easily in Python/Perl, however I want to try via the command line.

Comment: While programming of shell-scripts and problem with them are on topic here, the problem itself seems more on-topic on either http://superuser.com/, http://serverfault.com/ or http://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: this is the better answer found in the comments:

`find $DELDIR -type f -exec cp /dev/null "{}" \;`

The old answer is here:

`find $DELDIR -type f | xargs cp /dev/null`

where `$DELDIR` is the name of the directory to start in. The `-type f` option targets only files, not directories. And of course `xargs` just finishes off `cp /dev/null` with the file names from each line of find output.

Comment: So, when I do that I receive the following: `cp: target dir1/dir2/dir3/file.log` is not a directory.  When it finishes, nothing has changed.  If I am in the root directory with `dir`, I ran the command: `find dir1 -type f | xargs cp /dev/null`.

Comment: @espais Sorry, did you run into a file with spaces in it? Try this instead ```find $DELDIR -type f -exec cp /dev/null "{}" \;```

Comment: That did it, thanks.  However...there weren't any files with spaces.  There were quite a few underscores though.

Comment: @espais Awesome! Hmm, must have been some other characters that had to be quoted.

Answer (score 0):

carefully try:

```
find $DELDIR -type f | xargs cp -af /dev/null {} \;
```

Comment: sorry, @cptaffe 's answer is right. Just use `-exec`